# Cookie based redirect

Tags: php, cookies

I would like to set a cookie with an expiration time of 24 hours when a user enters Page A.

If the user visits Page B and he wasn't yet on Page A, he should stay on Page B.

However if the user visits Page B and the cookie from page A was already stored he should be automatically redirected to Page A.

Here is the PHP Code I inserted to the WP Plugin "My custom functions". Now my whole website ist just white and I can't do anything...

```
if( is_page('Page-A')){
    if(isset($_COOKIE['dz-offer'])){
        $cookie = $_COOKIE['dz-offer'];
    }
}
else{
    setcookie("dz-offer",time()+(3600*24));
    exit;
}

if( is_page('Page-B')){   
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['dz-cookie'])){
        header('Location: https://domain.com/page-a');
        exit;
    }
}
else{
   exit;
}
```

Any ideas how I can get that working? Thanks for your help!

+++ UPDATE +++

I deleted the Plugin "My custom functions" an now the white screen isn't there anymore... However if I reinstall the Plugin and activate it, the white space is there again before I can insert any code...

Comment: You have inconsistent cookie names. Some are called `dz-offer` others are called `cookie`. Anyway, there's no way for us to check your code. Please carefully read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Oh thanks! I just changed the cookie name.

Comment: Does it help to make it work? Also check all the `exit;`'s you use. If I read your code correctly it says: "If it is not page A then exit;".

Comment: No unfortunately it doesn't work... there is still a fatal error.

Comment: Missing ) closing the if statements..  if( is_page('Page-A') ) { will be correct

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it still doesn't work...

Comment: Ah there was still a ) missing after ('Page-B')... However know I can't acess my website anymore... It's just white...

Comment: You need to enable error display. Always when developing and testing PHP code, at the top of your script - `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`.  What you're seeing is called the "white screen of death", because a fatal error or failed redirect is hiding.

Comment: `setcookie()` and `header()` are sensitive to prior output and whitespace issues and the most common failures with them are described in [How to fix Headers already sent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: This logic is spaghetti

Comment: As I just said I'm not very familar with php coding... How would you do it?